# KDE - "/media/dev/path is a folder, but a file was expected" error

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, ubuntu-15.10

I have a Kubuntu 15.10 installation (fully updated). Sometimes when I try to copy some files/folder the OS throws "/media/dev/path is a folder, but a file was expected" error.
Screengrabs (Click on them to view):
[image: Screenshot]

How to fix this error?

Comment: Perhaps impacted by this bug?

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353195

Comment: Workaround: open two windows to make the copy.